# Do I need the package plasma-workspace on 18.04 with GNOME?

Tags: package-management, plasma

I have Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME. Do I need the package `plasma-workspace` or can I remove it?

Comment: How do you know you have this package? Maybe it's been pulled in as a dependency of something else you installed?

Comment: did you happen to install kde at any time or any of its apps?

Comment: I think in 16.04 I had the option to login to plasma instead of unity. Maybe it is from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the package *plasma-workspace* in Ubuntu 18.04 and you can safely remove it with `sudo apt remove plasma-workspace` if you haven't installed any packages that have *plasma-workspace* as a dependency.

Here are the reverse dependencies of plasma-workspace  in Ubuntu 18.04.

```
$ apt-cache rdepends plasma-workspace
plasma-workspace
Reverse Depends:
  plasma-workspace-dev
  sddm-theme-breeze
  plasma-workspace-wayland
  plasma-widgets-addons
  plasma-desktop-data
  plasma-desktop
  libkscreenlocker5
  kinfocenter
  kde-config-screenlocker
  drkonqi
  libkf5xmlrpcclient-data
  plasma-mediacenter
  openbox-kde-session
  libkf5globalaccel-data
  libkf5globalaccel-bin
  latte-dock
  kde-plasma-desktop
  kubuntu-web-shortcuts
  kubuntu-full
  kubuntu-desktop
```

The following command will show if any of these packages are currently installed.

```
apt policy plasma-workspace-dev sddm-theme-breeze plasma-workspace-wayland plasma-widgets-addons plasma-desktop-data plasma-desktop libkscreenlocker5 kinfocenter kde-config-screenlocker drkonqi libkf5xmlrpcclient-data plasma-mediacenter openbox-kde-session libkf5globalaccel-data libkf5globalaccel-bin latte-dock kde-plasma-desktop kubuntu-web-shortcuts kubuntu-full kubuntu-desktop
```